# Git show files unchanged for a period of time

Tags: git

I'm looking at a new repository and want to see which files are 'dead'.

One step is to find all the files in the repository that have NOT been modified in the past 6 months.

I've tried various versions of git log but can't figure out how to show the list of files that are unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty and I'm sure there's a more straight forward way but this will give you a list of files in descending order of modification date.

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD | while read filename; do   echo "$(git log -1 --format="%ai" -- $filename) $filename" >> /tmp/modDates; done
sort -rn /tmp/modDates
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a shell script with:

```
git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD | while read filename; do
  echo "$(git log -1 --format="%ad" -- $filename) $filename"
done
```

run script redirecting output to file.
Parse the file using regex, extract dates, compare to now-6 months.

Comment: Looks like we found the same answer trying to solve this one.